# Object.entries does not return expected result

Tags: javascript

I have an array that looks like this:

```
sim_data = [
  {
    "thumb_name": "Panel_BG_light",
    "thumb_file": "/media/media/3938493866/3938493866.jpg",
    "thumb_date": "2020-02-17T21:52:58.753408Z"
  },
  {
    "thumb_name": "Panel_BG_dark",
    "thumb_file": "/media/media/1247845432/1247845432.jpg",
    "thumb_date": "2020-02-22T11:13:28.937390Z"
  }
]
```

---

I use this function to get the images from the array:

```js
var panel_bg_light_;
var panel_bg_dark_;
var panel_background_light = sim_data[0];
var panel_background_dark = sim_data[1];

Object.entries(panel_background_light).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  panel_bg_light = value["thumb_file"];
  panel_bg_light_ = JSON.stringify(panel_bg_light);
  return panel_bg_light_;
});

Object.entries(panel_background_dark).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  panel_bg_dark = value["thumb_file"];
  panel_bg_dark_ = JSON.stringify(panel_bg_dark);
  return panel_bg_dark_;
});
```

I console logged the type of `panel_background_light` and it is an object, so why can't I access the `Object.entries` like this?

Thank you

Comment: That looks reasonable, if a bit repetitive, but `forEach` ignores its return value. Were you trying to have the `fromEntries` callback actually do something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.entries` returns an array of an objects key/value pairs. So the output of:

```
Object.entries({
    "thumb_name": "Panel_BG_light",
    "thumb_file": "/media/media/3938493866/3938493866.jpg",
    "thumb_date": "2020-02-17T21:52:58.753408Z"
  }
)
```

Looks like:

```
[
  ["thumb_name",  "Panel_BG_light"], 
  ["thumb_file", "/media/media/3938493866/3938493866.jpg"], 
  ["thumb_date", "2020-02-17T21:52:58.753408Z"]
]
```

If you only want to grab the value of 'thumb_file' why don't you just access it directly? ie.

```
var panel_bg_light_ = sim_data[0]['thumb_file'];
var panel_bg_dark_ = sim_data[1]['thumb_file'];
```